# Is your English getting better? or Does your English get better?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, present-tense, interrogatives, present-continuous, do-support

In a book, there's a question:

> Is your English getting better?

And not

> Does your English get better?

And

Where does you mum and dad live.

Where do your mum and dad live.

They both sound right to me.

Comment: @MaulikV There are four examples here.  Yes, the first two are grammatical, but they're very different in terms of meaning, so depending on what the OP wants to say, only the first may be okay.  As for the other pair, the third is ungrammatical, but the fourth is okay.

Comment: I had raised a question on *meta* (and probably you have commented/answered as well). Whenever there's an edit, leave commenter, even answerers aren't informed about it making their posts at times irrelevant. This is the latest example. The latter two examples are added later and I never knew that. :) @snailboat

Comment: @MaulikV Ah, I'm sorry, I didn't realize it had been edited.  Actually, it's unfortunate in this case―the questions are unrelated, and of the four answers, two address the former and two address the latter!  It'd be a real pain separating the questions out now...

Answer (score 4):

You should use the present progressive: *is your English getting better?* in most circumstances.

I would almost never say, *my English gets better.* The simple present is for characteristic, habitual, or repeated action, and, the way we normally talk about it, getting better at English is something that happens once. But we can imagine a person saying:

> Whenever I spend a few months home in Hungary, I tend to lose my confidence speaking English, and when I come back to London, I sound like a foreigner again. But *my English gets better* after a couple of weeks.

Comment: Whenever I talk with a native speaker, my English ***gets*** better! :)

Comment: Great examples.  We could also say: "When I started writing the book, I wasn't very good at English.  But don't worry!  Keep reading.  As the book goes on, my English gets better!"

Comment: I feel like, in both of these cases, the specific tense of *my English gets better* is governed by the need to agree with the first clause.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference has to do with the way *the passage of time* is involved and emphasized when using the *-ing* form.

```
is getting = is becoming with time

does get =  certainly becomes
```

Let's say two young lovers split up, and one of them is especially heartbroken. An older friend, who has been through this pain before, might give this advice:

**It will take time, but the sorrow you are feeling *does get better*.**

In other words, experience shows that this kind of sorrow usually fades. *It is a general truth or fact*.

After several months, the older friend and the sad younger friend meet again. The younger one might say:

**You were right. The sadness *is getting better*.**

The sadness it becoming less *with time*.

---

So, with respect to language:

**Language skills *do get better* with practice.** (a general truth)

**Your language skills *are getting better*.**  (from *practicing*; the improvement is happening over time)

Answer (score 0):

> Where does you mum and dad live.
>
> Where do your mum and dad live.

The second one is correct.  There are two people, so you have to use the third person plural form of the verb.

> He does.
>
> They do.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, whether to use

> Where does your mum and dad live?

or

> Where do your mum and dad live?

completely depends on the context.
If we are referring to them as living in two different places, we would say "do" because of the third person agreement/plural rule. However, if we are referring to them living in the same house, then "does" would be the correct choice.